# Getting Rita.WordNet to work

Tags: java, wordnet

According to [Rita Homepage](http://www.rednoise.org/rita/index.html) you just have to download Rita.jar and
WordNet-3.1 and add both to thebuild path of your java project.

I did it like that and everytime i try to use it:

```
RiWordNet wordNet = new RiWordNet(Test.class.getResource("/WordNet-3.1").getPath());
```

I get:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Unknown Source)
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(Unknown Source)
at rita.RiWordNet.initWordNet(Unknown Source)
at rita.RiWordNet.<init>(Unknown Source)
at rita.RiWordNet.<init>(Unknown Source)
at de.hof.iisys.relationExtraction.analyzer.utils.Rita.main(Rita.java:13)
Caused by: rita.wordnet.jwnl.JWNLException: The properties file must specify a dictionary path
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(Unknown Source)
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary.installStatic(Unknown Source)
... 10 more
Caused by: rita.wordnet.RiWordNetError: 
 [ERROR] Couldn't find file: .\WordNet-3.1\dict\index.verb
at rita.wordnet.WordnetDictionaryFile.openFile(Unknown Source)
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.dictionary.file.AbstractDictionaryFile.open(Unknown Source)
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalog.open(Unknown Source)
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalogSet.open(Unknown Source)
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.create(Unknown Source)
at rita.wordnet.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(Unknown Source)
... 11 more
```

Comment: You can download WordNet dictonary from here https://rednoise.org/rita/download.php

Answer (score 1):

The data files are no longer supplied as part of the installation. You need to download the WordNet version for your platform and then pass it to the constructor, as documented [here](http://rednoise.org/rita/reference/RiWordNet.html).